# How can we configure the proxy in the cordova inappbrowser

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

Any idea on how can we configure the proxy for the inapp browser in a android emulator?

Comment: I tried browsing http://google.com and it is not working, while it is working for some internal websites

Answer (score 0):

You can add proxy IP to proxy settings in Android Emulator Settings.

[image: Android Emulator Proxy Settings]